# Как задать интервал?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Почему rand()%5+2 выводит какие попало числа, хотя мне нужно от 2 до 5.

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
// ...   
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s[3] = s[2] = s[1] = s[0] = 'A' + i;
    sprintf_s(s1, "%s", s);
    strcpy_s(kl10[i].name, s1);
    kl10[i].year = rand() % 3 + 15;
    for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++) {
        kl10[i].ysp[m] = rand() % 5 + 2;
    }
    printf("Имя %s Возраст %d Оценки |%d|      n", kl10[i].name, kl10[i].year, kl10[i].ysp);
}
```

Comment: А зачем так много кода? Вопрос-то вообще про стандартную функцию.

Comment: @ReinRaus, вопрос-то был **не про интервал**, а про то, почему автор видит не то, что ожидает. Поэтому, когда после (не говорю вследствии) Вашего комментария кто-то убрал **"лишний" код** ответы потеряли смысл.

Скорее этот комментарий не к @ReinRaus, а к редактору вопросов. Между прочим, это уже не первый подобный случай.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что здесь:

```
printf("Имя %s Возраст %d Оценки |%d|      \n",kl10[i].name,kl10[i].year,kl10[i].ysp);
```

Вы печатаете **адрес** начала массива ysp[] в kl10[i], а не значение (какого не написано) **элемента массива**.

Comment: мне нужно напечатать все 10 значений массива ysp[], как это сделать

Comment: В цикле пишите.

    for (j  = 0; j < 10; j++) printf("Имя %s Возраст %d Оценки |%d|      \n",kl10[i].name,kl10[i].year,kl10[i].ysp[j]);

Comment: все разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

если вам нужно значение от 2 до 5 (включительно), то использовать надо так:

```
rand()%4+2
```

в этой строке получаем рандомное число (rand()) затем получаем остаток от деления на 4(%4) и прибавляем 2

**Добавлено:**

```
for(int m=0;m<10;m++){
        kl10[i].ysp[m]=rand()%5+2;           
        printf("Имя %s Возраст %d Оценки |%d|\n", kl10[i].name, kl10[i].year, kl10[i].ysp[m]);//было: kl10[i].ysp и за пределами цикла
}
```

Comment: @GALIAF95 обновил ответ.